# Today's date JSP

Tags: jsp

I've found myself working on some old JSP and want to do something simple like display today's date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Doesn't seem to be that simple,

So far I've imported java.util.*

And I've tried various things like

```
String df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
```

However, to no avail...

Comment: What does it mean does not work? Can you post your source code?

Comment: well, that is the source code, the error I get is "SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved or is not a type"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and then use some of the Calendar fields as needed, e.g.:

```
int dayOfMonth = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
String dayOfMonthStr = ((dayOfMonth < 10) ? "0" : "") + month;
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
String monthStr = ((month < 10) ? "0" : "") + month;
System.out.print(dayOfMonthStr+"/"+monthStr+"/"+now.get(Calendar.Year));
```

To follow your original idea, I think you should do something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: it works! thanks, I had to change it to "Calendar.YEAR" - do you know how to get the leading zeros?

Comment: which version did you use : the one with SimpleFormat or the one with calendar ?

Comment: for your second answer I get an error SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved or is not a type

Comment: thank you for putting the leading zeros in, I had to modify it because the true conditions were missing the day and month digits - but it works!

Comment: errors: need to move `int month...` up one line.. need to change last variable in `String dayOfMonthStr...` from `month` to `dayOfMonth`.. and change `Calendar.Year` to `Calendar.YEAR`

Comment: Minor typo...you will need to replace the now.get(Calendar.Year) with now.get(Calendar.YEAR)....its a constant....

Answer (score 16):

A cleaner approach *is* to use `JSTL` - `<fmt:formatDate/>` tags.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>    
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="long"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a z" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your given information you have imported java.util.* libraries. This is not enough. If you want using SimpleDateFormat you have to imported it. Add

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
```

to the top of your jsp file. After that define the format what you want to get

Example: `<%! final static String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd/MM/yy"; %>`

After that try

```
<%
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
%>
```

Comment: I get this error "Illegal modifier for the variable DATE_FORMAT_NOW; only final is permitted" so i took out the final static, the result of out.println(df) is this: java.text.SimpleDateFormat@927943a0

Comment: I checked it and updated the second code line in my answer. You cannot use plain 'println(df)'. If you read the java api, the last line calls just the cunstrotor from this class.

Comment: Here is a link http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/ that show some examples for the use of this method.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set date as

```
Date dNow = new Date( );
```

This coding helps to call date. Now, we have to set date format with coding as

```
new SimpleDateFormat ("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

This is the simple coding for date. If you need to make any other changes in font and position then you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

d will stores the current date only...it works
`<%
long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();

java.sql.Date d=new java.sql.Date(millis);
   %>`