# Display Current Date as default in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a field in jsp page where user needs to put a date. I want to display the current date in dd/mm/yyyy format as default whe the page first loads. Of courese the user can change the date from current date to any date. I have written the following code for this.

```
Date:
            <s:textfield name="fromTransactionDate" label="fromTransactionDate" readonly="true" title="dd/mm/yyyy format" onclick="ds_sh(this);" value="<%= new java.util.Date() %>"/>
                </td>
```

It gives the following error:

```
According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions
```

Then I have imported the jar jstl-1.2.jar and add tag lib as

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
```

Now when I write `<c:out value="<%= new java.util.Date() %>"></c:out>` the date is displayed, but  for

```
<s:textfield name="fromTransactionDate" label="fromTransactionDate" readonly="true" title="dd/mm/yyyy format" onclick="ds_sh(this);" value="<%= new java.util.Date() %>"/>
```

the error is still coming. I am not sure how to write in  or  filed so that todays date is displayed and also user can change it to other date.
Would really appreciate someone's advice.
Thanks

Comment: what taglib does s belong to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Today's date JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467341/todays-date-jsp)

Answer (score 4):

Try the next:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date">
<s:date name="now" var="formattedDate" format="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
<s:textfield name="enterDate" value="%{formattedDate}"/>
```

About `jsp:useBean` Zambon & Sekler (2007) says:

> The `useBean` action declares a new JSP scripting variable and associates it with a Java object.
>   For example, this code declares the variable `dataManager` of type `eshop.model.DataManager`:
>
> ```
> <jsp:useBean id="dataManager" scope="application"
>   class="eshop.model.DataManager"/>
> ```

<sub>─────────────────

REFERENCES

**Zambon, G. & Sekler, M.** (2007). *Beginning JSP, JSF, and Tomcat Web Development: From Novice to Professional.* Berkeley, Calif. New York: Apress Distributed to the Book trade worldwide by Springer-Verlage.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />

<s:textfield name="fromTransactionDate" label="fromTransactionDate" readonly="true" title="dd/mm/yyyy format" onclick="ds_sh(this);" value="${now}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>


<%
   Date date = new Date();
   out.print( "<h2 align=\"center\">" +date.toString()+"</h2>");
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to enter todays date in text field in jsp, try with below code,

```
 <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
 <%  Date date = new Date(); %>
 <input type="text" name="pInDate" value="<%= date.toString()%>"/>
```